# Using SQLPLUS command in UNIX scripts

Tags: oracle, bash, unix, sqlplus

I am trying to understand a simple script that connects to Oracle database using sqlplus command in unix:

```
1 sqlplus -s /nolog > /dev/null 2>&1 <<EOF
2 whenever sqlerror exit failure
3 connect $user_pwd
4 exit success
5 EOF
```

If I am using unix then I use commands as `sqlplus $user_pwd` for connecting to oracle database and to come out of `sqlplus` command I use `exit`. Please help me in understanding the lines 1,2,4,5. It may be a simple question for experts but I am not able to understand when to use these.

Comment: Try searching for _heredoc_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `-s` is for silent mode (not output anything)
- `> /dev/null 2>&1` things are for force to not display anything. (redirect standard output and standard error to /dev/null)
- `/nolog` is for not trying to login with the command line arguments. (the login credentials aren't provided here.)
- `<<EOF` is a heredoc input redirect. The lines until `EOF` will be passed to `sqlplus` as standard input. (So this is why the last line is `EOF`)
- About the `whenever` line: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm  So the command's return value will be failure if something wrong happens.
- `connect $user_pwd` connects the `sqlplus` to the server
- The `exit success` makes sqlplus returning will success. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12023.htm#i2697968